# Grid row selection in mvc view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

In my MVC application, I am using a `webgrid` to display user details in the view. In each row it has a column with a radio button to select that row.

In the same view it has a form also. If the user selecting a row by clicking on the radio button, then the corresponding details should fill in the form control. Then the user can edit the details from that form.

How can i filter a particular user details based on the row id and fill it in the form? Can I use LINQ in jQuery function for this?

This is my View,

```
@model IEnumerable<MyTestProject.Models.modeldata>
@{
    Layout = null;
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 5,selectionFieldName:"SelectedRow");
}
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!DOCTYPE>
<style type="text/css">
    .gridTable {margin: 5px;padding: 10px;border: 1px #c8c8c8 solid;border-collapse: collapse;min-width: 550px; background-color: #fff;color: #fff;}
.gridHead th{font-weight: bold;background-color: #030D8D;color: #fff;padding: 10px}
.gridHead a:link,.gridHead a:visited,.gridHead a:active,.gridHead a:hover {color: #fff;}
.gridHead a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
.gridTable tr.gridAltRow{background-color: #efeeef;}
.gridTable tr:hover{background-color: #f6f70a;}
.gridAltRow td{padding: 10px;margin: 5px; color: #333;}
.gridRow td{padding: 10px;color: #333;}
.gridFooter td{padding: 10px; background-color: #c7d1d6;color: #999;font-size: 12pt;text-align: center;}
.gridFooter a{font-weight: bold;color: #333; border: 1px #333 solid;}
</style>
<html>
    <head runat="server">
        <title>EDIT with Grid</title>
    </head>
<body style="padding:10px">
        <div>
<div> 
                @grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "table",
    fillEmptyRows: false,
    headerStyle: "header",

    footerStyle: "grid-footer",

    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",

    columns: new[]  // colums in grid
    {
        grid.Column(header: "Select", format: @<text><input name="chck" type="RADIO" id="chck" class="rbutton" value="@item.id" /></text>),
        grid.Column("name"  ),
        grid.Column("age"),
        grid.Column("email"),
        grid.Column("mob"),
   })
            </div>
<form>
                <h2>Edit User Details</h2>
                <div class="space">
                    <div>Name</div>
                    <div>@Html.TextBox("txtname")</div>
                </div>
                <div class="space">
                    <div>Age</div>
                    <div>@Html.TextBox("txtage")</div>
                </div>
                <div class="space">
                    <div>Email</div>
                    <div>@Html.TextBox("txtmail")</div>

                </div>
                <div class="space">
                    <div>Mobile</div>
                    <div>@Html.TextBox("txtmob")</div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin-top:20px">
                    <input type="submit" id="ButtonSave" value="Save" />
                </div>
</form>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.rbutton').click(function () {
        try
        {
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            $('#txtname').val(row.children('td').eq(1).text());
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            alert(ex.message);
        }
    });


</script>
```

And, my model class is,

```
public class modeldata
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string mob { get; set; }
    }
```

And finally the controller is,

```
public ActionResult EditUser()
        {
            List<modeldata> lmd = new List<modeldata>();
            DataTable dt = Db.GetUserDetails();
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                lmd.Add(new modeldata
                {
                    id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]),
                    name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                    age = dr["Age"].ToString(),
                    email = dr["Email"].ToString(),
                    mob = dr["Mobile"].ToString()
                });
            }
            return View(lmd);
        }
```

Comment: Are all the details need for editing available in the row, or do you need to use a ajax to call a server method to return the details?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: yes. all the user details need for editing are available in the row.

Comment: Remove the awful `onclick="..."` and give the buttons a class name and use `$('.radiobutton').click(function() { var row = $(this).closest('tr'); ....` and then you can get the values from the cells in the row and update the form elements. You have not shown any html so can't be any more specific

Comment: @StephenMuecke : I have edited my question. Please check my webgrid and form. Thanx.

Comment: You really need to show the actual html your generating for a typical row, but expanding on my first comment - `$('#txtname').val(row.cells.eq(1).text());` should set the value of the first textbox in your form to the value of the 2nd (name) cell in the selected row.

Comment: @StephenMuecke :  '$('#txtname').val(row.cells.eq(1).text());' is giving an error 'row.cells is undefined'

Comment: Well I don't know what the html your generating is so its just a best guess :) If you show it I'll be able to give you an answer. And you should also show the model and the signature of the POST method so I can correct the form so you get proper model binding

Comment: Oops - it should be `row.children('td').eq(1).text()`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : just now i added view, model and controller to my question. "row.children('td').eq(1).text()" is giving empty value. "alert(row.children('td').eq(1).text());"  is showing an empty alert message.

Comment: You have not  shown the actual html your generating (use your developer tools to inspect a typical row element) - my suggestion was based on it being `<tr><td>yourRadioButtonHtml</td><td>theValueOfTheNameProperty</td><td>etc...</td></tr>`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : ok. sorry.  Is there any way to get user details from the Model based on ID in jquery? Can I use Linq in jquery function to retrieve details from Model?

Comment: jquery has no concept of Linq :). Without see the actual html for a typical row I cannot give you the correct selectors. But another option is to add the value as `data-` attributes - `<input type="RADIO" class="radiobutton" data-name="@item.Name" ...etc />` (remove the invalid `id` attribute and the unnecessary `name` attribute) and then `$('.radiobutton').click(function( $('#txtname').val($(this).data('name')); ...etc )};`

Comment: @StephenMuecke : Thanks. "$('.radiobutton').click(function(){      $('#txtname').val($(this).data('name'));});" this is working fine. If you are ading this as an answer, surely I will accept it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to add the values of you model to the radio button as `data-` attributes and read then in the script.

Change the html for the button to

```
<input type="radio" name="chck" class="radiobutton" data-name="@item.name" data="@item.age" ..... />
```

and in the script

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function() {
  $('#txtname').val($(this).data('name'));
  $('#txtage').val($(this).data('age'));
  ....
});
```

Another is to use relative selectors to read the values from the table cells in the associated columns. You have not shown the actual html generated by you code, so the following may need to modified to suit

```
<input type="radio" name="chck" class="radiobutton" />
```

Script

```
$('.radiobutton').change(function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the associated row
  $('#txtname').val(row.find('td').eq(1).text()); // get the text of the 2nd cell in the row
  ....
});
```

Note the following with regards to the above code:

1. Remove your `id` attribute from the radio button - your generating
   duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html
2. Remove the `onclick` attribute (don't pollute you markup with
   behavior) and use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

I also recommend you change the way you are generating the form to make use of model bind and allow client and server side validation

Create a partial view (say) `_UserData.cshtml`

```
@model modeldata
<form id="userform">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.name)
    .... // elements for other properties
    <button id="save" type="button">Save</button>
</form>
```

And in the main view use

```
@Html.Partial("_UserData")
```

And assuming your submitting using ajax so that you can edit multiple users without leaving the page, the script in the main view would be

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Edit")';
$('#save').click(function() {
    $.post(url, $('#userform').serialize(), function(response) {
        if (!response) {
            // display error message the the user was not saved?
        }
    });
});
```

which would post back to

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Edit(modeldata model)
{
    // save the data
    return Json(true); // or return Json(null); if something failed
}
```

Note that in the above scripts, the selectors would need to be change to match the actual `id` attribute generated - i.e. `id="name"`, not `id=txtname"` etc.

```
$('#name').val($(this).data('name'));
```